# Use OptaPlanner for my Java application

Tags: java, algorithm, tabu-search

I developed a heuristic in Java to solve a variant of VRP with real data and additional attribute (such as barcode for items). 
Now I need a Tabu Search framework in order to use the Tabu Search technique.
I tried with OpenTS but there are no significant examples and that framework has not been updated so I ask: is it possible to use OptaPlanner to run the Tabu Search algorithm in my application?